# Scheduled jobs during server shutdown doesn't run during server startup

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have configured the simple trigger scheduling program using JDBCJobStore. Everything is working fine, until server is running, but if server breaks down and later restarted, the job's that are missed to trigger during server down time is not triggered after restarting the server. But the scheduled jobs after restart are also working fine.

Eg: If 3 jobs are scheduled as below:

```
Job 1 - 15-April-2014 9 AM
Job 2 - 15-April-2014 9:30 AM
Job 3 - 15-April-2014 10 AM
```

For the above case, the job 1 is executed as expected, now the server is stopped from 9:15 AM to 9:45 AM, here job 2 is missed to execute. Later after restarting the server at 9:45 the Job 2 is not triggered. But at 10 AM the job 3 is triggered and execute as expected.

I don't know what I missing out. Do I need to add any specific property or in Java code during scheduling job. So that quartz can trigger job 2, please someone help me to find the solution for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have resolved the above issue by using Misfire policy -  MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_RESCHEDULE_NOW_WITH_EXISTING_REPEAT_COUNT. But my new problem is that, I am unable to trigger the Job that was in-progress during server shutdown/Crash. I surfed the net and found 'RequestsRecovery', though I set it as true, on the server restart the job was not recovered. Could someone help me out to overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Once the server down all schedule jobs will go's down.
at the time of server starting you need to resubmit all jobs to RAM

```
SchedulerUtility schedUtil=new SchedulerUtility();
        try {

            Scheduler sched = schedUtil.getScheduler();
            sched.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e);
            //e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            log.error(e);
            //e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

make sure that u need to execute this every time when server start/restart